# Nginx regex to exclude certain paths

Tags: regex, nginx

I am trying to exclude some paths in my nginx proxypass and want everything else to go to my proxypass.

i.e I dont want to give proxy_pass to any url which starts with 'tiny' or 'static', but want everythign else to go to my proxypass location.

and I am using following regex to achieve this:

```
~ ^((?!tiny|static).)*$
```

But I always get 404 error.
If I navigate to following url in browser

```
localhost:8080/xyz
```

I want it to go to

```
localhost:8000/api/tiny/records/xyz
```

Can someone please help me in pointing out what is the issue ?

Here is my full nginx conf file:-

```
server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;
        location   ~ ^((?!tiny|static).)*$ {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:8000/api/tiny/records/$1;
        }
        location   / {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:8000;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where should `/tiny` and `/static` URIs go? You only have two `location` blocks and both `proxy_pass` to the service on port 8000.

Comment: @RichardSmith
/tiny and /static should go to root path in the 2nd location,

My 2 location blocks proxy_pass to the service on port 8000 but different directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `/` and have the `*` in the wrong place. The regular expression should be:

```
^(/(?!tiny|static).*)$
```

But you do not need to use a regular expression with a negative lookahead assertion. Instead, place a normal regular expression on the other location block.

For example:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8000/api/tiny/records/;
}
location ~ ^/(tiny|static) {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

Just add this for  .git folder restrictions

Comment: What part of this relates to `.git/` folders?